# How to blink SpritekitNode?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

i want to blink `SpritekitNode` when two player and monster collapse . im using code in `didBeginContact`:

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;
}
else
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyB;
    secondBody = contact.bodyA;
}

if ([firstBody.node.name isEqual: OBSTACLE_KEY] && ( [secondBody.node.name isEqual: PLAYER_KEY] ))
{

    if ([kPref integerForKey:BUY_LIFES] > 0)

    {
        SKAction *blink = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:0.25],
                                               [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:0.25]]];

        SKAction *blinkForever = [SKAction repeatAction:blink count:3];


        [secondBody.node runAction: blinkForever];

        int life = [kPref integerForKey:BUY_LIFES] - 1;
        [kPref setInteger:life forKey:BUY_LIFES];
    }
    else
    {
        [kPref setInteger:sec forKey:HIGH_SCORE];
        self.paused =YES;
    }
}
}
```

it working but it continuously call `didBeginContact` when monster touches player node till it connected to it, i want to set in way that if monster node touch player than it blinks 3 times and that period of time none monster can touch player node.
Please help me out.!

Comment: then clearly blinking isn't the problem here but contact events. Show us that code.

Comment: updated code with didBeginContact method.

Comment: If the two bodies continue to be in contact, they'll continue to fire the contact event, which means you'll be running multiple "blink" actions which probably interfere with each other.

You can prevent that by checking if an action is already running on the secondBody.node - provided that it does not run any other actions. Otherwise you'd have to run the action with a key and check if an action with that key is already running.